# How can I initialized the generics attribute of object?

Tags: typescript

I have the code like below

```js
class Eventful<T extends string> {
  // ↓ How can I initialized this attr without ts error?
  private eventMap: Record<T, (args?: any) => void> = ?
}
```

Or

```js
class Eventful<T extends string> {
  private eventMap!: Record<T, (args?: any) => void>

  constructor() {
    this.eventMap = ?
  }
}
```

so, what I should do? thx.

I try to initialized the attribute with

```js
function addEvent(key: T, handler: (args?: any) => void>) {
  this.eventMap = {
    [key]: [] as EventHandler[]
  }
}
```

but it also cause error with ts(2322) in VSCode.

Comment: Why would you try to assign an array to a function?

Comment: oh..., it should be `((args?: any)=>void)[]`, I missed `[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for the declaration you should use `as` to prevent repeating of the type:

```
class Eventful<T extends string> {
    private eventMap = {} as Record<T, ((args?: any) => void)[]>;
}
```

also, it should be a Record of strings to arrays of functions. Then you can use `push` to add the handler in `addEvent`:

```
    addEvent(key: T, handler: (args?: any) => void) {
        if (!(key in this.eventMap)) this.eventMap[key] = [];

        this.eventMap[key].push(handler);
    }
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mL2VKw)